Interlaced HDMI is not working on Pi4 Bookworm
I've a Pi4 with Bookworm (CLI, no desktop). I'm trying to get 1080i50 output from the HDMI, but the Pi keeps sending progressive on the output.
Everything is freshly newly installed (so up to date).
I've forced the mode in cmdline.txt: "video=HDMI-A-1:1920x1080M@50i", but the output is always P.
The EDID lists interlaced as an available mode. Using dtoverlay=vc4-kms-v3d or dtoverlay=vc4-fkms-v3d doesn't change anything. I also tried X11 instead of Wayland, without any luck.
What else could I do/try...?
Thanks in advance for your help,
Eddy

trying to use fkms on Bookworm is futile as is ANYTHING to do with video in config.txt; cmdline.txt has NOTHING to do with display; you can't use X11 or Wayland if you don't have a desktop. Why don't you install a normal OS?

Beacuse it is lighter...
If I try with 'modetest -s 32:1920x1080i-25', I get an interlaced output. However the framebuffer is still showing in progressive...
Thanks
